# Wordpress categories and subcategories posting

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple question.

I have a category named "active" and there are subcategories of the same active-1, active-2, active-3

Now there is a post which is related to subcategory active-3.

So shall I add this post to active-3 subcategory only, or both active-3 subcategory and category active?

What's the difference in both?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s suppose you are creating a travel website for different destinations around the world. You may want users to be able to find articles by city and by country as well.
For example, you can add United States and then post articles for New York City, Los Angeles, Chicago, etc. This is where you can utilize child categories. United States would become a parent category, and cities can become child categories.
It is important to note that a post filed under a child category does not need to be filed under parent category. For example, if you assign a post New York City as category which is a child category of United States, then you are free to choose whether you want the post to be filed under both or just the child category.
If you choose to file a post under the child category but not under the parent category, then your post will appear only on the archive pages of child category. This particularly helpful when you want to avoid duplicate content.
Let’s suppose you have created a parent category United States and it has only one child category, New York City. Now if you file a post under both parent and child categories, then the archive pages of both categories will be completely identical.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Suppose if I add that to only child category and not main category, then how will the main category page look like?